# Decode the ANSWER. Can you do it?

Tags: cipher

> In some code the word EXAM is written as OVSG and TEST is written as ZOAZ then the word ANSWER is written in that code as:

I tried to figure it out and it's harder than I expected. Admittedly though, I am a newbie at this.

Edit: The question is from one of the engineering entrance exams in India. They don't release official question papers so this is memory based. But there is no doubt about the question being wrong. It has been decoded by some already.

Comment: Where is this from?

Comment: It's pretty easy to solve substitution cipher. Just write down the 26 letters of the alphabet in a row, and underneath write what those letters get encoded to for the letters in the given words, and try to recognise the pattern.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yeah, I will try again. Thanks! Apparently, some mirroring thing is going in the middle so I got confused

Comment: Which exam exactly? When did you take it? Do they allow their questions to be posted on the Internet?

Comment: This is just a Caesar shift, I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER IS

> SFAWOB

Pattern:

> Start A from S and go to reverse order.
> ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
> SRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBAZYXWVUT